# Why does accessing ParticleSystem.IsAlive() raise this error?

Tags: unity, c#, particles

I am trying to record if my particle system `IsAlive` with:

```
GameObject prefab = Instantiate (Prefab, myPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

Component ps = prefab.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ();
bool checkIfPSPlaying = ps.IsAlive ();
//bool playing = prefab.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().isPlaying // This works fine
```

The code above gives this error:

**error CS1061: Type *UnityEngine.Component* does not contain a definition for *IsAlive* and no extension method *IsAlive* of type *UnityEngine.Component* could be found**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set `ps` to the correct type (it should be a particle system). Try something like this:

```
GameObject prefab = Instantiate (Prefab, myPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

ParticleSystem ps = prefab.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ();
bool checkIfPSPlaying = ps.IsAlive ();
```

Comment: If your code depends on the prefab having a particlesystem attached, it's helpful to show this in the type of the variable - that way the inspector will enforce this constraint at level creation time, rather than letting any errors slip through until runtime. eg... `public ParticleSystem effectPrefab; void SpawnEffect() { ParticleSystem effect = Instantiate<ParticleSystem>(effectPrefab); effect.transform.position = myPosition; bool checkIfPlaying = effect.IsAlive(); ... } `

Comment: @DMGregory, what you sounds important, but I don't quite understand... I should let ***effectPrefab*** know it belongs to *** myPrefab*** before I instantiate it (this is like a sanity check I guess?). But then when I assign  ***effect***, it points to an empty ***effectPrefab***?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, @BonnieB. In this example, you'd use `effectPrefab` to store the reference to your prefab, so you wouldn't have a separate `myPrefab` variable. When you instantiate `effectPrefab`, Unity spawns the whole object (not just the particle system part), and returns a reference to the instance's particle system. You don't have to do it this way, it's just a style choice that has some data validation benefits, and saves a separate `GetComponent` call.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an object to a variable with the type of its base class (like `Component` which is the base-class for all components, including `ParticleSystem`) you only get to call [those methods which are defined in the base class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html).

When you want to call methods which are defined in a more specific class, you need to assign the object to a variable of that more specific type. Like this:

```
ParticleSystem ps = prefab.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ();
```